Convert this to an array to output specific positions in the array
I'm looking for converting this list to an array so I can output specific strings from there. How could I do this? Here is the code:
 public override void Select()
 {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder($"{MenuText()}{Environment.NewLine}");
     int i = 1;
     foreach (string file in _reader.paths)
     {
         sb.AppendLine($"{i}. {file}");
         i++;
     }
     Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
     int selectedIndex = ConsoleHelpers.GetIntegerInRange(1, _reader.paths.Count, MenuText()) - 1;
     string[] result = File.ReadAllLines(_reader.paths[selectedIndex]);
     if (result.Length == 0)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Cannot open file - No data found");
     }
     else if (result.Length > 0) 
     {
         var splitedStringList = new List<List<String>>();
         foreach (string file in result)
         {
             var tmp = file.Split(':').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
             splitedStringList.Add(tmp.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList());
         }
     }
 }

I tried using '.ToArray' at the end of the list, but that didn't seem to work.

List.ToArray Method. "Copies the elements of the List to a new array."

As far as I can see, you want to

Show the menu
Open a file based on user choice from the menu
Split each file lines by ':'
Return all non-empty chunks as an array

If it's your task
// Show the menu
Console.WriteLile(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, _reader
  .paths
  .Select((file, i) => $"{i + 1}. {file}")
  .Prepend(MenuText()));

// Get index
int selectedIndex = ConsoleHelpers
  .GetIntegerInRange(1, _reader.paths.Count, MenuText()) - 1;

// Query the file
result = File
  .ReadLines(_reader.paths[selectedIndex])
  .SelectMany(file => file
    .Split(':', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries | StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  .ToArray();

if (array.Length == 0) 
  Console.WriteLine("Cannot open file - No data found");

